# Patterns for loading related objects in memory (without an ORM)

Tags: design-patterns, database, domain-driven-design, entity-framework, orm

I am using ADO.NET to read a bunch of data from the database into in-memory objects.

This is my domain model:

```
// Question.cs
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

// Tag.cs
public class Tag 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On retrieving the list of Questions, I would like to fetch the related tags for each question. I am able to do this as follows:

```
// QuestionRepository.cs

public IList<Question> FindAll()
{
    var questions = new List<Question>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from questions";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Question question = new Question();
                // Populate the question object using reader
                question.Load(reader);

                questions.Add(question);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
     }
    return questions;
}


// Question.cs
public void Load(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    ID = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
    Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
    Description = reader["Description"].ToString();

    // Use Tag Repository to find all the tags for a particular question
    Tags = tagRepository.GetAllTagsForQuestionById(ID); 
}

    return questions;
}

// TagRepository.cs
public List<Tag> GetAllTagsForQuestionById(int id)
{
    List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> ();
    // Build sql query to retrive the tags
    // Build the in-memory list of tags 
    return tags;
}
```

My question is, are there any best practices/patterns for fetching related objects from the database?

Most of the SO questions I came across for loading related data provide the solution for entity framework. There is no answer for this [duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282164/load-related-entities-using-classic-ado-net)

Even though my code works, I would like to know other ways to do the same. The closest explanation I came across that's targeting my particular problem was Martin Fowler's [Lazy Load](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) pattern, which I believe, will result in following implementation:

```
public class Question
{
    private TagRepository tagRepo = new TagRepository();
    private IList<Tag> tags;

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags {
        get
        {
            if (tags == null)
            {
                tags = tagRepo.GetAllTagsForQuestionById(ID);
            }
            return tags;
        }
    }  
}
```

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Your link above shows you already found a good reference to this question: Fowler's book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html). Unfortunately, questions which require a whole book as an answer are definitely too broad for the Q&A format of this site, so don't be disappointed if your question gets closed by the community for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you always need all tags for each question, then lazy loading is not the best approach.

Instead, I would join the tables directly in SQL. Something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from questions 
                       inner join questiontags on question.id = questiontags.questionid
                       inner join tags on questiontags.tagid = tags.tagid";
```

Now you can create your question object and all tag objects inside a single database call.